# Golang api (with buffalo) retrieve Post datas

Tags: api, post, go, multipart

I am developing an API in Golang (with Buffalo library).

I have my route set to point to :

```
func (ur UserResource) Create(c buffalo.Context) error {
    // new User
    u := &models.User{}
    if err := c.Bind(u); err != nil {
        return c.Render(500, r.String(err.Error()))
    }
    id, _ := uuid.NewV4()
    u.ID = id
    db[u.ID] = *u
    return c.Render(201, r.JSON(u))
}
```

The problem is that when I test my api I have the following error :

(and my header `Content-Type` is set to `multipart/form-data`)
 [image: Problem]

If I change the way values are passed to `form-url-encoded` and set no header, I have this error :
`invalid character 'i' in literal false (expecting 'a')`

Comment: Are you setting your Content-Type to `form-url-encoded` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: I'm sorry, if iI pass values via `form-url-encoded` I set no header. If I set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` I get back to `EOF` error

Comment: Try `curl -d "firstname=Boris&lastname=Le+Meec" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users`, if it goes through successfully it's possible that the app you're using to send the api requests is constructing those requests in some manner that buffalo (or the libs it uses, or Go) can't handle.

Comment: Nop. I still have an error (the same `EOF`)...

Comment: Do you have any middleware, or some code that runs before `UserResource.Create`? Something That reads the `req.Body` without resetting it?

Comment: Nope, the only code that calls `UserRessource.Create` is `g.POST("/users", ur.Create)` (`g` is a `Group` with `/api/v1`)

Comment: If you've no calls to `a/g.Use` that could read the body, and you're certain a body is being sent in the request, and you're still getting `EOF` then i'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: `c.Request().FormValue("firstname")` actually returns `Boris` so I think I won't user any binder, just gonna do it by hand